# Counting occurence of an element with a specific value in a different column

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I have a csv file with two columns, one for rating and one for the comment. I want to count how many times '!' occurs in comments, and give the corresponding values according to ratings. For example I want to say, the rating is 5 and '!' occurs 545 times within the comments that have 5 rating. I have a counter but it does not specify the rating. So far I tried this

```
counter = 0
import csv
searchpm = '!'
with open('Reviews.csv', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
        for line in csv.reader(f):
            if line.df['Score'] == 5:
                if any(searchpm in l for l in map(str.lower, line)):
                      counter += 1

print(counter)
```

Gives the error: 'list' object has no attribute 'df'
How can I print out how many times '!' occurs in each score from 1 to 5?

Comment: What is `df` supposed to point to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use defaultdict for show how many times '!' occurs for each score.

```py
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

counter = defaultdict(int)
searchpm = '!'

with open('Reviews.csv', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    next(f)  # for skip first row with headers
    for line in csv.reader(f):
        counter[str(line[0])] += line[1].count(searchpm)

print(counter)
```

Comment: it gives too many outputs but I am looking for only 5 values, how many '!' does comments with 1 score has in total, how many with 2 and etc. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you get something other from this `defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'1': 3, '2': 3, '3': 10, '4': 11, '5': 15})` i think you doing something wrong

Comment: It gives the number of '!' in every cell I guess, like this: {'1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 0, '5': 0, '6': 0, '7': 0, '8': 0, '9': 0, '10': 0, '11': 0, '12': 0, '13': 0, '14': 0, '15': 0, '16': 0, '17': 0, '18': 0, '19': 0, '20': 0, '21': 0, '22': 0, '23': 0, '24': 0, '25': 0, '26': 0, '27': 0, '28': 0, '29': 0........

Comment: Check that `line[0]` is rating and `line[1]` is comment. Maybe you have other column order.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is a better option for reading this csv file.

```
df = pd.read_csv('Reviews.csv')
```

Then, you can create a new column to check if the column 'Comment' has the char '!'.

```
df['checkchar'] = df.comments.apply(lambda x: '!' in x)
```

Finally, to get how many comments on each score has the char '!', a groupby does the job.

```
>>> df.groupby('Score').sum().reset_index()
     score  checkchar
0      1    1.0
1      2    5.0
2      3    20.0
3      4    101.0
4      5    545.0
```